# How to publish dist files that are into .gitignore

Tags: git, npm

I have a project with the follow tree

```
/
dist/
some-folder/
package.json
```

I'm using .gitignore file to ignored dist folder and .npmignore to ingore all files except dist folder, but when I publish my package I have some-folder also.
How to fix it?

Comment: Have you got any nested `.gitignore` or `.npmignore` files? They might be interfering with the top-level rules.

Comment: could you add the contents of your `.npmignore` to your question?

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is just "publishing" (to a registry such as npmjs) dist files, then you can easily do this using the [prepack lifecycle script](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/using-npm/scripts#life-cycle-scripts). So in my library projects, I use:

```
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "prepack": "yarn build",
  },
```

This publishes dist to the npmregistry using `yarn publish` even though `dist/` is inside .gitignore.

P.S. Like @miqh mentioned in comment, ensure dist is not listed in the `.npmignore` file. That would conflict and cause issues.